# How to insert a python NUMERIC type in postgresql REAL type column

Tags: python, postgresql, numeric

I have a column in postgresql defined as REAL[] type, and when I try to insert a value in the column it results in an error.

The value is an array of numbers, like this: `[23.4, -45, 7895]`

And the resulting error is: `operator does not exist: real[] = numeric[]`

What should I do?

Comment: IMHO It is best to use `numeric` type in postgres table. Floating point types are rarely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect it's not the insert part of your query that's the problem:

```
db=# create temp table fnord ( foo numeric[] );
db=# insert into fnord values ('{23.4, -45, 7895}'::real[]);
db=# insert into fnord values ('{23.4, -45, 7895}'::real[]);
db=# select '{23.4, -45, 7895}'::numeric[] = '{12, 12, 12}'::real[];
ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric[] = real[]
LINE 1: select '{23.4, -45, 7895}'::numeric[] = '{12, 12, 12}'::real...
                                              ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Time: 77.539 ms
```

You probably have a comparison somewhere in your query. Fix that with a cast, and you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, I have a comparison before the insert. So that's the problem, not in the insert but in the comparison.